# How can I show array and button by click?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a simple table with buttons: `<button class='btn btn-info' href='#'>More</button>`, and I need that when user click by "More" button then array ($records, for example) and "Less" button will be shown under "More" button. For example, `$records[0]="1", $records[1]="2"`. Please, I don't know JavaScript and JQuery very well, but I need to do it using Ajax. So, I very need your help. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

```
$("button.btn-info").click(function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

It's code for clicking by "More button", but I don't know how to write $records array under this button with "Less" button (which will hide the array by click) at the end.

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot id. I need that all buttos are members of one class, but depending on clicked button user will see different arrays

Comment: where you want to show the more "Details" ? can you write more or show snap

Comment: I have table with 2 columns: 1 column - field, second column - "More" button. When user click by button, I need that the array will be shown under the button. At the end of the array I need to add button "Less" - if user click by "Less" button the array must be hide. Please, help me with it. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: **@userX** id's can't start with a number. Well not entirely true tho, cuz HTML5 allows it but I won't recommended it.

Comment: Sorry, I "id" mustn't be number. I have deleted it

Comment: The arrays will be shown? The code itself? Am not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Do you know PHP? I have described in subject.

Comment: Yes, I know PHP, you did not mention php in your post.

Comment: I need to show $records array (PHP-array). I have described it in my post.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned php just now, and you will get more downvotes for not explaining your problem in detail. Revise the content of your problem.

Comment: I have just update my answer. Check it please. I hope you can help me now.

Comment: See my answer below (**spoon-fed**). Please learn php, jquery, js.

Answer (score 1):

PHP (sample only):

```
<?php
   $records = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="more">
    <button>More</button>
</div>
<div id="less" style="display: none;">
    <div id="codes" style="border-top: 1px dotted #d0d0d0;">
        <?php
           for($i=0; $i<count($records); $i++) {
              printf("$records[%d] = %d<br />",$i,$records[$i]);
           }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    $('div#more button').click(function() {
        $('div#less').toggle();
        if (i) { $(this).html('Less'); i=0; } else { $(this).html('More'); i=1; }
    });
});​
</script>
```

P.S. Do not forget to include the jQuery plugin or this won't work.

EDIT: There it is `jquery.min.js`

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fe9wv/

Comment: Also please, add "Less" button. You forgot it.

Comment: @user1477886 The `More` button is replaced with `Less` when you click, don't you like it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery for this, below is a rough example
Assumptions: 
ALL the buttons have an ID(required for fetching data through ajax)
The table cell in which you have the button ,also has a  with display style as hidden and class as 'dataspan'

```
      $('.btn-info').live('click',function(){
           var id = $(this).attr('id');
           $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
        url: "YOUR TARGET URL",
                    dataType : "HTML",//you can also use JSON
                    data     : 'id=' + id,
            success: function(data)
           {

                       $(this).siblings('.dataspan').html(data);
                       $(this).siblings('.dataspan').append('<button class="hidedata"  value="HIDE"/>');
                       $(this).siblings('.dataspan').show();
           }
    }); 
      });

//FOR hiding the data
$('.hidedata').live('click' , function(){
      $(this).siblings('.dataspan').hide();
});
```

Please note that as per the latest JQuery release the .live function has been deprecated, if you are using the latest version I will strongly recommend you to switch to delegate function